# syntax error near unexpected token in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I coded a small script to fetch some urls

```
#!/bin/bash
input_file="urls.txt"

function convert_to_bpp
{
  local filesize=$1
  local bpp
  bpp=$(echo "(($filesize * 8) / ($width * $height))" | bc -l)
  printf -v bpp "%0.2f" "$bpp" #set to 2 dp
  echo "$bpp"
}

image_count=0
images_names=()
while read -r  url && [[ "$image_count" -le 10000 ]]; do    
    wget "$url"
    filename=$(basename "$url")
    width=$(identify -format "%w" "$filename")
    height=$(identify -format "%h" "$filename")
    new_size=$(wc -c < "$filename")
    new_size_bpp=$(convert_to_bpp "$new_size")
    if (( $(echo "$new_size_bpp > 8" |bc -l) )); then
        echo "$url" >> hq_urls.txt
        image_count=$(( image_count + 1 ))
        images_names+=("$filename")
        echo "$image_count"
    else 
        rm -rf "$filename"
    fi  
done < "$input_file"
zip "quality_images.zip" "${images_names[@]}"
```

bash -n getimages.sh

```
getimages.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
getimages.sh: line 8: `}'
```

I have already check the script with [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and used `dos2unix` but they couldn't detect the error.

`GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Can you copy the script from your post into a new file and verify that it still shows the problem?

Comment: BTW, your code will be less gratuitously incompatible with other shells if instead of writing `function convert_to_bpp {` you wrote `convert_to_bpp() {` -- the `function` keyword is a ksh extension adopted by bash, not part of the POSIX sh standard.

Comment: That said, the issue is not reproducible with the code as given here -- see your function running perfectly without any changes whatsoever at https://ideone.com/67ibKk

Comment: Also tests OK on bash 4.4.12(1)-release

Comment: Something that might cause confusion if you have more than one version of this script.  If you run `getimages.sh` it will use `$PATH` to find the script, which might not include the current directory.  If you use `bash -n getimages.sh` it will look in the current directory for the script.

Comment: I copied paste my own code from this post into a file and it worked.I still don't know what caused the issue